# React Native and globally accessible objects

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am having a really terrible time with React Native and being able to access functions, variables and objects from within deeper levels of functions.  I honestly thought [Redux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redux_(JavaScript_library)) would be my saving grace here, but I am running into exactly the same hurdle with this too.  An example:

```
export class Home extends React.Component {

static propTypes = {
    navigation: PropTypes.object,
    dispatch: Proptypes.func,
};

componentDidMount() {
    Firebase.init();
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
            this.setState({ loading: false, user });
            firebaseUserID = this.state.user.uid;
            this.props.dispatch(setUserID(firebaseUserID));
            firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Profiles").child(this.props.userID);
            firebaseRef.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
                firebaseUserName = snapshot.child("Name").val();
                this.props.dispatch(setUserName(firebaseUserName));
                console.log('Logged in user: ' + this.props.userName);
            });
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Map');
        } else {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Login');
        }
    });
}
```

In this example, the first call to my Redux stuff is perfectly fine:

```
this.props.dispatch(setUserID(firebaseUserID));
```

This grabs the correct username and saves it to my Redux store.  No problem.

The error is with this line:

```
this.props.dispatch(setUserName(firebaseUserName));
```

Because it is called one level deeper than the previous statement, therefore the context of "this" is different.  It is part of the sub-function below and so this.props doesn't exist here even though literally four lines above it is fine:

```
firebaseRef.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
```

As soon as I have to make sub-functions (which is *all of the time* because this is how code works), I lose the ability to access all of the resources that are required to make the app work.

I have been hacking my way through with dodgy workarounds and superfluous recreation of variables, but enough is enough now. I need this to work properly like a normal language.   So, what am I doing wrong?   How am I supposed to create objects, functions and variables so that I can actually use them?

How can I work out the specific example above?

Comment: Try replacing with `firebaseRef.once("value").then((snapshot) => {`

Comment: Hi Pritish, thank you for your reply.   I can't work out where to put the closing bracket to your opening bracket.   It doesn't accept it anywhere.   Can you post this as an answer, and if it works I will accept it?

Comment: I meant to replace `function(snapshot)` with the `arrow function` `(snapshot) =>`, because it is losing it's binding.

Comment: Oh sorry!  I should have just copied and pasted it, I read it wrong.   Wow!   Why does that work!?  You are a modern genius sir.   Post an answer so I can give you the points!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not have its own `this, arguments, super, or new.target`.

Since your function `firebaseRef.once("value").then(function(snapshot)` is not bound therefore it is losing the context of `this`.

Therefore the simplest way would be to use an **arrow function** to bind it as `firebaseRef.once("value").then((snapshot) =>`

Comment: I also have a follow-on question to this one here, if you want more points:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50212127/react-native-arrow-functions-and-if-statements