# react native arrow functions and geoQueries

Tags: react-native, arrow-functions, geofire

I am still struggling a little bit with arrow functions.  I have previously made these posts:

- [react native and globally accessible objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50209526/react-native-and-globally-accessible-objects)
- [react native arrow functions and if statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50212127/react-native-arrow-functions-and-if-statements)

But now I am having a new issue with how these can be used with geoQuery.  I have tried the code shown below:

```
    myFunction = () => {

    var onKeyMovedRegistration = () => geoQuery.on("key_moved", function(key, location, distance) {
        console.log('Test log');
        if (key != this.props.userID) {
            arraySearchResult = findKeyInArray(key, this.props.arrayOfKeys);
            if (arraySearchResult != "keyNotFound") {    
                console.log(key + " moved within query to " + location + " (" + distance + " km from center)");
            }
        }    
    })
    }
```

So myFunction is bound, and I am trying to bind the geoQuery as well, as otherwise this.props.userID and this.props.arrayOfKeys are not accessible if I use the original line:

```
var onKeyMovedRegistration = geoQuery.on("key_moved", function(key, location, distance) {
```

With the attempt above, nothing fires.  I do not get "Test log" to the console.   There is no crash or error, it's just clearly not how this is supposed to be done.

Anyone know how I can get past this one?

Comment: First and foremost try replacing with `geoQuery.on("key_moved", (key, location, distance) =>` and check the result.

Comment: You are just too good mate.   Please submit this as an answer so I can accept it.   Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `geoFire` `listener` function is *not bound* therefore you can't access class level props to it.

Therefore the simplest way would be to use the arrow function here as

```
geoQuery.on("key_moved", (key, location, distance) =>
```

After this, `this` will be bound to the class and you will be able to access the class level props.